# Comments tab in user area/profile?

Tags: feature-request

This would aid all users in being able to see their comments along-side the questions and answers tabs.

I often find myself wondering how I can look at the comments I've made in isolation to other content (and|or) sort them by type: (all|voted|deleted).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all the comments you've posted in your [profile's activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714488/nickhar?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: But I can't filter them in any way - only "view all". Given that they form a major part of commentary, don't they justify a more major role? I often see more votes for comments than any answers...

Comment: @nickhar Major role? No, comments are third class citizens, they are only meant for clarifications and they can disappear at any time.

Comment: Ironically, I upvoted your comment for downgrading them to the level of third-class citizens. ;)

Comment: I said part of commentary, not role. But fair enough.

Comment: @nickhar They are not part of the commentary, they _are_ the commentary. And commentary is not significant in a Q&A site.

Comment: Sorry. I've seen many solutions and answers in comments, so I beg to differ. They are significant to many, just not to you personally.

Comment: @nickhar You are correct, many people abuse comments (especially posting answers in comments), however they are only meant to be temporary post it notes. For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment